# Flutter beginner for fun, why my code didn't display last widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a Flutter newbie with zero experience as a programmer. In my spare time i am taking a course on Flutter and i have created an APP to test my knowledge.
It is a simple game where you need to press the buttons in sequence and when they are all pressed, an end game widget is displayed.
I'm stuck because I can't see the latest FineGioco widget.
Thank you so much for the help you will give me. I Post the code below, and sorry for my English.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './button_control.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: const Text('Gioco Bottone')),
        body: ButtonControl(),
        //FineGioco(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

button_control.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './finegioco.dart';

class ButtonControl extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonControlState createState() => _ButtonControlState();
}

class _ButtonControlState extends State<ButtonControl> {
  final FineGioco testoFineGioco = FineGioco('Hai FINITO IL GIOCO');
  bool settaVisibilita1 = true;
  bool settaVisibilita2 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita3 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita4 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita5 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita6 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita7 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita8 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita9 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita10 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita11 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita12 = false;
  bool settaVisibilita13 = false;

  //FineGioco() => {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita1,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita1 = false;
                        settaVisibilita2 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita2,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita2 = false;
                        settaVisibilita3 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita3,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita3 = false;
                        settaVisibilita4 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita4,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita4 = false;
                        settaVisibilita5 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita5,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita5 = false;
                        settaVisibilita6 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita6,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita6 = false;
                        settaVisibilita7 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita7,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita7 = false;
                        settaVisibilita8 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita8,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita8 = false;
                        settaVisibilita9 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita9,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita9 = false;
                        settaVisibilita10 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita10,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita10 = false;
                        settaVisibilita11 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
            Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita11,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        settaVisibilita11 = false;
                        settaVisibilita12 = true;
                        settaVisibilita13 = true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi'))),
            Visibility(
              visible: settaVisibilita13,
              child: Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita12,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      settaVisibilita12 = false;
                      settaVisibilita13 = true;
                      setState(() {
                        testoFineGioco;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Premimi')),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

finegioco.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FineGioco extends StatelessWidget {
  final String textFineGioco;
  FineGioco(this.textFineGioco);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        (textFineGioco),
        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Cannot find a way to render this last widget.

Comment: please read this article first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you mean the widget you commented out in Scaffold´s body, it is because you can only assign one widget to body. If you want to assign more, consider using a column or listview instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/// In buttonControl Class add 
  bool settaVisibilita14 = false;

///in your  column under
Visibility(
          visible: settaVisibilita13,
          child: Visibility(
            visible: settaVisibilita12,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  /// Pressin on this button will set your widget to visible
                  setState(() {
                  settaVisibilita14 = true;
                  });

                },
                child: const Text('show me FineGioco')),
          ),
        ),
  // Add this
  // Here the widget will only appear if settaVisibilita14 is true
  Visibility(
          visible: settaVisibilita14,
          child: FineGioco(),
          
        )
```

Comment: Really thx for the reply, but Listview or Column do not resolve my issue. I try to explain better the problem. The problem is that i wanna display the Class FineGioco only when last Button is pressed. If  i recall class FineGioco in the main is always displayed, but my goal is display FineGioco Widget only when last button (in the button_control Class) is pressed. Sorry for my explanation, i'm a very newbie in coding, thx to all for the reply!

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong
you want the FineGioco widget to appear when you press the last button ( the one with Visibility(
                visible: settaVisibilita12,
                ...))

Comment: Yes Oussama that is exactly my goal, really thx